# How to add/hook new function into admin-ajax.php permanent

Tags: wordpress, hook, admin-ajax

I add function 'listing_companions_Ajax' into **$core_actions_post** of **admin-ajax.php**. But discover **after WP update** that function is **not present anymore**.

```
$core_actions_post = array('oembed-cache',...,'listing_companions_Ajax');
```

> Question: how can I add / hook this new function listing_companions_Ajax to the file admin-ajax.php without missing it after an WP update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for ajax using on WordPress :

This is the javascript.

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: siteUrl.ajax_url + '?action=listing_companions_ajax',
        data: someDataHere,
        success: function (response) {
          // do something on success here
        }
 } );
```

WordPress:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_listing_companions_ajax', 'listing_companions_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_listing_companions_ajax', 'listing_companions_ajax' );

function listing_companions_ajax() {
 // do smth here
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Never write a custom code in WordPress code files. If you want to use ajax please consider reading this article - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes I know now why you dont do that. Do you have an example how to include it as a hook?